# AWS Lambda Function to convert files to PDF - Nodejs - Error executing function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently creating an AWS Lambda function to convert office files to pdf using LibreOffice in a Lambda Layer.

So I have used code from a developer and I'm trying to make it work but every time I try something else I get another error, this time I feel I'm close to success but the following error keeps appearing when I test the function:

"errorType": "TypeError", "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')", "trace": [ "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')", " at Runtime.module.exports.handler (/var/task/index/index.js:36:23)", " at runMicrotasks ()", " at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"

The original post I'm following is at the below link:

https://madhavpalshikar.medium.com/converting-office-docs-to-pdf-with-aws-lambda-372c5ac918f1

The code I'm using is below:

```
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
const {writeFileSync} = require('fs');
const lambdafs = require('lambdafs');
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const inputPath = path.join( '/opt', 'lo.tar.br'); 
const outputPath = '/tmp/';
const bucketName = 'doc-conversion-tests';

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(execSync('ls -alh /opt').toString('utf8'));

  try {
    // Decompressing
    let decompressed = {
      file: await lambdafs.inflate(inputPath)
    };

    console.log('output brotli de:----', decompressed); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error brotli de:----', error);
  }

  try {
    console.log(execSync('ls -alh /opt').toString('utf8')); 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  var body = "";
  //S3 put event
  body = event.Records[0].body;
  console.log('s3 bucket file name from event:', body);

  // get file from s3 bucket
  var s3fileName = body;
  var newFileName = Date.now()+'.pdf';
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
  var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/'+s3fileName);

  var getObject = function(keyFile) {
      return new Promise(function(success, reject) {
          s3.getObject(
              { Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyFile },
              function (error, data) {
                  if(error) {
                      reject(error);
                  } else {
                      success(data);
                  }
              }
          );
      });
  }

  let fileData = await getObject(s3fileName);
    try{  
      fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/'+s3fileName, fileData.Body);
    } catch(err) {
      // An error occurred
      console.error('file write:', err);
    }

    const convertCommand = `export HOME=/tmp && /tmp/lo/instdir/program/soffice.bin --headless -    -norestore --invisible --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --nologo --convert-to "pdf:writer_pdf_Export" --outdir /tmp /tmp/${s3fileName}`;
    try {
      console.log(execSync(convertCommand).toString('utf8'));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(execSync(convertCommand).toString('utf8'));
    }
    console.log(execSync('ls -alh /tmp').toString('utf8'));

    function uploadFile(buffer, fileName) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.putObject({
       Body: buffer,
       Key: fileName,
       Bucket: bucketName,
      }, (error) => {
       if (error) {
        reject(error);
       } else {

        resolve(fileName);
       }
      });
     });
    }


    let fileParts = s3fileName.substr(0, s3fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".pdf";
    let fileB64data = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/'+fileParts);
    await uploadFile(fileB64data, 'pdf/'+fileParts);
    console.log('new pdf converted and uploaded!!!');
};
```

Can someone please help me to fix the error as I'm losing the will to live?

Please help!! - All suggestions welcomed.

Many thanks

I have tried adding a document name (test.doc) instead of a "0" but made no difference, as indicated there is a problem @ line 36 but no idea what to try next.

Comment: It seems that the function is trying to access a property that is undefined. Can you print the event and make sure that "event" has the "Records" property and then check it has the "body" element.

Comment: Sorry how do I do this?

Comment: I have tried again adding the name of the .xml file in place of the [0] and it generated a pdf, but my belief is the code should find any newly uploaded file and trigger it.  var body = "";
  //S3 put event
  body = 'XML16Q62317.XML';
  console.log('s3 bucket file name from event:', body);

Comment: How are you testing your code?, You can add the following lines of code before line 36 in order to print the event in the console and visually see the format of the event, can you post the resulting message for further help. console.log('Event content:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)); // prints the content in a more readable manner

Comment: I'm testing via a Lambda function and error is generated from there

Comment: Can you share the test event used?

Comment: Did you try putting an object in S3 and check if the lambda function process the triggered event?, It seems that the error is generated because of the event’s format